# C#: Control.Invoke or TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

If I'm on another thread and want to interact with the UI thread, I have two options; either chain my main task to a `ContinueWith` method and pass the `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` to it so that it executes on the UI thread or from the background thread (task) itself, pass a delegate/lambda expression to the `Control.Invoke` and manipulate the UI there;

I'm advised to always use the first option and never go the other way; why? is something wrong with the second procedure in comparison with the first one?

Comment: It will be TaskScheduler that uses Control.Invoke().  "Never" is a rather black and white, rarely appropriate.  It is white because your code still works when used in a WPF or Modern UI app.  Only *really* matters when it is in a library.  It is black when you have to use Control.Begin/Invoke because the task was created on a worker thread and FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() cannot work because there is no current synchronization context.